# AASM transition from but except one state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

I have AASM with ActiveRecord model.

Have many statuses and events with their transitions.
I want to create event that will allow transition from any state except one.

```
event :set_vacant_pass do
  transitions to: :vacant_pass, from: ??
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, i just decided to have simple solution:

```
event :set_vacant_pass do
  transitions to: :vacant_pass, from: Vacation.man_statuses.except('vacant_pass').keys
end
```

This will allow event transition from any state except `vacant_pass`.

(`man_status` is enum column and used for `AASM`)

Answer (score 0):

Spitballing so syntax may not be perfect, but you can specify this explicitly using a list.  Supposing your valid states to transition to "vacant_pass" from are "new", "created" and "closed":

```
event :set_vacant_pass do
  transitions from: [:new, :created, :closed], to: :vacant_pass
end
```

Or you could use a guard

```
event :set_vacant_pass do
  transitions_from: Vacations.man_statuses.keys, to: :vacant_pass, guard: :transition_valid?
end

def transition_valid?
  self.state == :vacant_pass
end
```

Added extra, you can use

```
ClassName.aasm.states.map(&:name)
```

to get an array of symbols containing all possible states for your class.